# Assembly Language: + vs add

Tags: assembly, x86

I am a university student studying assembly language on my own time. I noticed that while there are instructions like add and mul, arithmetic operators are often used within instructions. For example:

```
mov eax,[ebx+ecx]
```

Is it **equivalent** to the following?

```
add ebx,ecx
mov eax,[ebx]
```

(ignoring the change in the contents of ebx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as reading something from memory they are functionally the same.  The differences already mentioned you dont modify the flags when used strictly for register offset addressing [ebx+ecx], and that you modify ebx and destroy your base address.   You also consume twice as many instructions, twice as many fetches.  x86 being variable instruction length this doesnt necessarily mean twice as many bytes worth of instructions, but it does mean more clock cycles and more cache space consumed to perform the same task.

Hopefully you will continue to study assembly on your own time and I recommend studying other instruction sets as well (ARM, thumb, mips, msp430, avr, etc).  You will often see these tradeoffs, sometimes you specifically want to do that add without destroying a register and without modifying the flags.  Sometimes you want or need register offset addressing to make the code faster or cleaner than having to consume a register and an extra instruction for every reference on every loop for example.  Knowing that many processors have register offset addressing you can write your high level code to take advantage of these things if you are interested in performance for example, both generic and target specific.

Answer (score 3):

Nearly... 
This index address method ([ebx+ecx] or any other) is normaly used for addressing elements in some array or record. In your case the **ebx** can be a pointer to byte array and **ecx** is an index. Using index addressing can be dangerous because there is no efected flags after arithmetic operations so we can't check array range overflow. Normaly high level compilers in debug mode use clasic slower method, so that we are able to detect array range overflow. When we switch compiler to relase mode (and we are sure that there is no more possible bugs) the faster index addressing method is in use.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not equivalent. If this is real code, then the thing inside the brackets is an example of an [addressing mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addressing_mode). The addressing mode controls how the effective address for the operation is computed, but it typically does not have a persistent effect. Your second code snippet actually adds to the `ebx` register, changing its contents for any following instructions.

Update: I just saw your last sentence about ignoring the change ... If you want to ignore that, then yes, I believe the two snippets are equivalent.